# how to get external ip of the server from node.js

Tags: node.js, nowjs-sockets

I'm using now.js and there's this line that refers to localhost. In order for someone to access the server outside I need to modify localhost to be the current external ip of my computer(my ip is dynamic). Is there any way to detect the current external ip from the script?

```
window.now = nowInitialize("//localhost:8081", {});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could ask an external service like [this one](http://fugal.net/ip.cgi) (which is nice because it returns it without formatting).

To use it, you could use [Node's built in `http` module](http://www.nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback):

```js
require('http').request({
    hostname: 'fugal.org',
    path: '/ip.cgi',
    agent: false
}, function(res) {
    if(res.statusCode != 200) {
        throw new Error('non-OK status: ' + res.statusCode);
    }
    res.setEncoding('utf-8');
    var ipAddress = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk) { ipAddress += chunk; });
    res.on('end', function() {
        // ipAddress contains the external IP address
    });
}).on('error', function(err) {
    throw err;
});
```

Keep in mind that external services can go down or change — this has happened once already, invalidating this answer. I've updated it, but this could happen again…

Comment: how do I get the ip returned from the site?

Comment: This won't work anymore, the site now shows the ip address in an image.

Comment: @DanRoss: I found another service that does the same thing. I'm not sure I would go as far as to say it's *fixed*, but at the very least it works again…for now.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe there isn't a standard way to get this from my server's ISP.

Comment: @DanRoss: Well, if the server isn't behind a NAT, you can look at the interface addresses, but if you're behind a NAT, that will get your LAN IP.

Comment: Crap. It looks like my dev server is truly inaccessible from the outside world, and that this is how the Internet is supposed to work. I wanted an easy way to try using OpenId on my site, without having to use a different provider in development and production, but maybe that isn't possible. I guess I'll set up a local OpenId server so that I can authenticate myself as a user and redirect myself back to localhost.