# How to get the current server IP of request when multiple interfaces are used?

Tags: ip, meteor

Sorry, but I was not able to find the answer for this simple question after two attempts of googaling:

How can I get the current IP of the server connection a client is handled on? Is it possible to extract this somehow [Meteor.status()](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_status)?

(Background: we have different IPs which are served by the same instance. But we like to distinguish by the IP entry point.)

Answer (score 0):

Meteor.status() don't have the information. But you can publish the IP address to the client or make a method that return it.

This is a pseudo-code and I don't know if this works. It's just an idea:

server.js:

```
var THIS_IP = '8.8.8.8'; // Try to get it dinamically with node or some npm package
Meteor.methods({
  'serverIp': function () {
    return THIS_IP;
  }
});
```

client.js:

```
Meteor.call('serverIp', function (err, serverIp) { //do something with the IP });
```

EDIT: Sorry about this response. Just saw you have 2 IPs in same server. Maybe this hack can solve problems for now?
[how to get external ip of the server from node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962111/how-to-get-external-ip-of-the-server-from-node-js)